# How to Prove Removing a Below-Expectation Element Increases Expected Value

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, expected-value

I am trying to prove that the expected value of Q will increase if I remove a below-expected-value element from the possibility space.
While it seems intuitively obvious, I'm having trouble with the proof part.

Essentially, for each possible outcome $Q_i$ that occurs with probability $p_i$, I have:
$$ E[Q] = \sum_i p_i Q_i $$
So, let us say there is a $Q_x$ where $Q_x$ < $E[Q]$, and I remove it from the pool and then renormalize.
The new expectation will be:

$$ E[Q]_\text{new} = \left(\sum_{i \neq x}p_iQ_i\right)\left(\frac{1}{1 - p_x}\right)$$

Here, the $\frac{1}{1 - p_x}$ is a renormalizing factor to adjust the probabilities so that they add up to 1 after the removal of the $Q_x$ possibility.
What I can't seem to wrap my mind around is to how to prove that, if $Q_x < E[Q]$ then $E[Q]_\text{new} > E[Q]$.
Is there a standard inequality for this?
I'm sure I'm missing something dumb, so even a simple push in the right direction would be helpful.

---

EDIT: This is my attempt based on @RonaldBlaak's suggestion.  Please let me know if this is correct.

Start:
$$ E[Q] = \sum_i p_i Q_i \\ 
E[Q]_\text{new} = \frac{\sum\limits_i p_i Q_i - p_x Q_x}{1 - p_x}
$$
We want to know the conditions so that $E[Q]_\text{new} > E[Q]$. We will then start by saying:

$$ \sum_i p_i Q_i < \frac{\sum\limits_i p_i Q_i - p_x Q_x}{1 - p_x} $$

We can then transform as follows:

$$ \left( 1 - p_x \right) \sum_i p_i Q_i < \sum_i p_i Q_i - p_x Q_x \\
\left( \sum_i p_i Q_i \right) - p_x \left(\sum_i p_i Q_i\right) < \sum_i p_i Q_i - p_x Q_x \\
-p_x \left(\sum_i p_i Q_i\right) < -p_x Q_x \\
\sum_i p_i Q_i > Q_x \\
E[Q] > Q_x
$$
Therefore, I can deduce from this that $Q_x < E[Q]$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for $E[Q]_\text{new} > E[Q]$.

Is that a correct procedure?

Comment: It is probably the typo that you made twice. The $p_x < E[Q]$ should be $Q_x < E[Q]$

Comment: @RonaldBlaak - thank you - you are correct.  I edited the post to correct it.

Comment: Then it is really just starting with the inequality you want to prove, multiply both sides with $(1-p_x)/p_x>0$ , and swap some terms

Comment: can you prove it for two terms, $Q_1,Q_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, $0<p_x<1$.

\begin{align}
E[Q]_{new} &= \left(\sum_{i \ne x} p_i Q_i \right)\left(\frac1{1-p_x} \right) \\&= \left( E[Q]-p_x Q_x\right)\left(\frac1{1-p_x} \right)
\end{align}

Hence

$$E[Q]_{new}-p_x E[Q]_{new} = E[Q]-p_xQ_x$$

$$\iff E[Q]_{new}-E[Q]=p_x(E[Q]_{new} - Q_x)$$

Hence it sufficies to verify that $E[Q]_{new} > Q_x$. that is

$$\left( E[Q]-p_x Q_x\right)\left(\frac1{1-p_x} \right)> Q_x$$

which is just $E[Q]>Q_x$.

---

Edit:

Comments on your working: Good writing.

Replace "We will then start by saying" with "we want to prove/ verify that" and state that each step is equivalence statement from the previous step.

Comment: It is great to give an answer, but many students just want to learn how to do it by themselves, rather than reading a complete answer